# Diferencia entre objeto y variable dentro de la clase del tipo clase

Tags: vb.net, poo

Tengo la siguiente clase:

```
Public Class Book
    Public isbn as Integer

    Sub New(isbn as Integer)
        Me.isbn = isbn
    End Sub
End Class
```

Todo bien, si yo quiero crear una variable de instancia tengo que pasar parámetros para el constructor y todo normal, pero cual es la diferencia entre una variable de instancia:

```
Public NuevoLibro as New Book(isbn)
```

Y tener una variable del tipo clase dentro de la clase (en este caso he creado una variable llamada libro):

```
Public Class Book
    Public isbn as Integer
    Public libro as Book

    Sub New(isbn as Integer)
        Me.isbn = isbn
    End Sub
End Class
```

Este ejemplo es en visual basic, pero en java también se puede hacer, así que supongo que esto inclusive tiene nombre.

Comment: una variable es un string, array, int ; un objeto es un new Clase(); no entiendo muy bien tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Realmente la sentencia que hay dentro de la clase Book es la declaración de una variable de instancia, pero no inicializada:

```
Public libro as Book
```

Es decir, libro no contiene nada.

```
Public NuevoLibro as New Book(isbn)
```

Aquí has declarado un objeto (*NuevoLibro*) del tipo *Book* y lo has iniciado pasando el valor *isbn*

Answer (score 0):

Creo entender tu pregunta.

En el paradigma de programación orientado a objetos, las clases tienen relaciones entre sí. Cuando tienes un objeto de una clase que hace parte de los atributos de una segunda clase hablamos de una relación llamada **"tiene un"** (o de  Agregación para ser más técnicos). Por ejemplo:

```
public class Libro  {
   private Autor autor; // la variable autor es un objeto de tipo Autor
   private int numeroCopias;
   private String nombre;

   public Libro() {
       this.autor = new Autor();
       // constructor, casi siempre acà inicializarias el/los atributos de tipo clase
   }

   // mas metodos...
}
```

Para el fragmento de código anterior, se dice que un Libro **"tiene un"** Autor. La variable *autor* de tipo *Autor* no es más que un objeto no inicializado, necesitado por la clase *Libro* para realizar sus procesos (tal vez existen métodos en *Autor* que son necesarios para que la clase *Libro* funcione correctamente).

Cuando haces

```
Libro milibro = new Libro();
```

Entonces instancias el objeto *milibro* (cosa que creo que ya sabías). Por último te recomiendo que leas este articulo en español: https://sekthdroid.wordpress.com/tag/relacion-is-a-java/. Saludos y espero haber aclarado tu duda.